# Python Excel Cross Multiply

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to make a simple python script that will cross multiply two columns in excel. For example:

[image: chart]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/greni.jpg

The first column is A,B,C and the second column is D,E,F. I wish to have columns 3+4 have the two columns cross multiplied against each other.

Code so far:

```
import openpyxl


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('list.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet')

i=1
maxRow = len(sheet['B'])

for rowNum in sheet.columns[1]:
    for rowNum2  in sheet.columns[2]:
    sheet.cell(row=i,column=3).value=sheet.cell(row=rowNum,column=1)
    sheet.cell(row=i,column=4).value = sheet.cell(row=i%maxRow,column=2)
    i += 1

wb.save('updatedlist.xlsx')
```

What is the best way to get the maxRow length so that I can divide by the modulus?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just detect the max row based on when the values stop? Anyway, have you looked into using Pandas? It would make quick work of a problem like this

Comment: I'm not sure about your API, but when I was using POI I had to just look for a  row with blank content in the first cell and call it the "end" and use the number of entries I had encountered as a count.  Isn't that pretty much what your rowNum loop does?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is all of the permutations of column A values and column B values, I would recommend reading in both columns and then computing those directly:

```
# use pandas to read in the excel file
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("filename.xlsx")

# get the permutations (assumes your columns have headers "A" and "B" respectively)
import itertools
result = list(itertools.product(df["A"].values, df["B"].values))

# write back out to a file
output = pd.Series(results).apply(pd.Series)
output.to_excel("result.xlsx")
```

Comment: Traceback:File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3078, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'B'

Comment: What does your file actually look like? You're getting this error because there's no column with header name "B." By default, Pandas uses the first line in the file as the header. If your file has no headers, it would use numeric column names, so you would replace df["A"] and df["B"] with df[0] and df[1] respectively. Would be helpful if you could post a screenshot of your file in Excel. If it's just the first two columns of your original screenshot, then use df[0] and df[1] like I mentioned